Value at Risk / Tail Value at Risk
Question: Let X be a random variable with the following loss distribution
    k   Pk
    0  0.50
 1000  0.30
 2000  0.10
 5000  0.06
10000  0.04

– Calculate 95% value-at-risk.
– Calculate 95% tail value-at-risk.
Hi everyone, above is the question I would like help with. I tried the formula
value-at-Risk (%) = [Expected Return – (St. Dev of Portfolio x Z-score of Confidence Interval)]. However, the answer is negative which doesnt look right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I think you've misunderstood VaR. It's a quantile of a loss distribution. By the looks of it you've been given a discrete loss distribution so should calculate VaR from that directly. The formula you're plugging into (wherever it came from) has no meaning here.

@statsplease, do you know the formula to work it out? I believe you have to work out the standard deviation, expectation, variance and use the z score which is 1.96? I am getting various formulas online so slightly confused. Or is it a cumulative approach?

Those formulae you are getting online aren't going to be very useful. You already know the loss distribution, it's the $P_k$. VaR is defined as a quantile of that distribution. Given this is homework, how has VaR been defined in your coursework?

@statsplease, Its revision for an exam not hw. Would I be right in saying you need to work out the cumulative probability, so 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.96 and 1. As it's 95% VaR, it would be just under 0.96 which means K is 5000, the answer?

That looks correct
